# Get branch name without remote

Tags: git, bash, gitlab-ci

I would like to get the branch name in GitLab-ci in a `.yml` markup.

```
stages:
  - a

a:
  stage: aa
  script:
      - make BRANCH=...
```

Somehow using `$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)` gives me
`remotes/origin/mybranch`

I would like `mybranch` instead.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Or the current branch is already defined in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

On Git 1.8+, another way of getting only the `HEAD` branch name is with

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
```

This command will not work on a detached `HEAD` state, where there is no a "branch".

Answer (score 0):

You can get current branch name by the following command.

> git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD